# Delphi 2007 - Hide all forms to system tray if modalresul equal mrCancel

Tags: delphi

I have a two forms: frmMain and frmLogin. The frmLogin is a available form and its created when a frmMain is "activated":

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
If (frmLogin = Nil) Then 
frmLogin := TFrmLogin.Create(Application); 
frmLogin.WindowState := wsNormal; 
frmLogin.Showmodal;
frmLogin.free;
frmLogin:=nil;
end;
```

In the frmLogin i changed button1 modalresult to mrOk:

```
procedure TfrmLogin.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if Edit1.Text = '123456' then
 begin
modalresult:=1;
fechar:=true;

end else begin
application.MessageBox(pchar('Wrong Pass'), 'Login não autorizado',Mb_Ok+mb_iconerror);
modalresult:=0;
end;
```

And in the button2 i changed the modalresult to mrCancel.  But I need that when the user clicks the cancel button in the login form is closed and the main form is hidden, showing only the trayicon. I used the following code in button2:

```
frmMain.visible: = false
```

but it is returning an error "Can not change Visible in OnShow or OnHide". Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the message loop to postpone the Hide to a later moment:

```
const
  WM_USERCANCEL = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TForm245 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  protected
    procedure WMUSERCANCEL(var Message: TMessage); message WM_USERCANCEL;
  public
  end;

procedure TForm245.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If (frmLogin = Nil) Then
    frmLogin := TFrmLogin.Create(Application);
  frmLogin.WindowState := wsNormal;
  if frmLogin.Showmodal = mrCancel then
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_USERCANCEL, 0, 0);
  frmLogin.free;
  frmLogin := nil;
end;

procedure TForm245.WMUSERCANCEL(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Visible := false;
end;
```

Comment: You've got a typo: WM_USER -> WM_USERCANCEL. Anyway, IMHO, it would be better to suggest postponing the modal showing of the login form instead of postponing hiding of the main form.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Thanks, fixed. I know there are better ways to do it, but this seemed the least invasive. I also didn't mention that there is no more need for the login form to know about the main form.